# How do White work on already running application?

Tags: c#, white-framework, microsoft-ui-automation

I am using testStack/White library to automate an application. Right now its working fine but it throws exception if the application is already running. Is there any way to put a check e.g if application is already running then do not invoke it. i mean, then we can skip this line of code

```
Application application = Application.Launch(@"someapplication.exe");
```

I could not find any good documentation of White.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could do:

```
Application application;
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(@"someapplication");
if (processes.Length == 0)
  application = Application.Launch(@"someapplication");
else
  application = Application.Attach(@"someapplication");
```

happy coding

Comment: Had to remove `.exe` part.

Comment: This is the exact code / logic I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Or easier

```
Application application = Application.AttachOrLaunch(@"someapplication.exe");
```

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back on the previous answer, to find the name of the application you want...

1) Open the task manager, 
2) find the process you want to use with white
3) right  click on the process you want and select properties
4) The name to use is in the textbox.  Usually doesn't have .exe.